# I am getting an error using fetch_object() in a SELECT statement with NOT IN Clause

Tags: sql

i.e Say:

```
select 
  * 
from tblname 
where col1 NOT IN array;
```

have problem using NOT IN.... but not when i do: `col1 = 'singlevalue';` Please help

Comment: and what is the problem? show full sql request which causes your problem

Comment: I can't believe I answered this question.

Comment: if you're getting an error: _please_ post that error-message!

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM ABC HAVING ID NOT IN $_SESSION[preferences]'"; $result = $mysqli->query($query);$row=$res->fetch_object();Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Comment: so, now it's "from... HAVING ..." - in the question above it's "from... WHERE ..." - whats the one you're trying to do? i think HAVING might be the problem, WHERE is what you should use in this case.

Comment: I have an array that currently holds 1,3..i.e $arr = {1,3}; i want to frame a query as the one i gave above.. as follows: $q = "select * from tbl where col1 not in ('$arr')"; That works fine... Next i execute it.. $res=$mysqli->query($q); That also works.. Next i need to display the resultset returned by $res. But i get an error when i use: $row = $res->fetch_object(); the error is with the last query... which works when i use: select * from tbl where col1 = '1'; The "NOT IN" query works drectly in the database...

Comment: The query as i have given to u all works fine when it is queried on the database directly... i.e. in mysql directly... Encounter the fatal error only when i try to retrieve the result, i.e. using fetch_object(), which works fine when i use select.. where col1 = '' and not in: "select ... where col1 NOT IN ('1,....');

Comment: even this does not work: $query = "select * from tbl where col1 NOT IN '(1,2)'";

Comment: Let me try to make my question simple to understand:  I need to select * from tbl where col1 NOT IN $array, and print the qualified rows... Hw is that to be done?

Comment: it has to be "select * from tbl where col1 NOT IN (1,2)", not "select * from tbl where col1 NOT IN '(1,2)'" (look at the single quotes - if you would have executed this diectly, you would have got an error and don't need to ask this)

Comment: @oezi.... that works... but in case u use a dynamic array... is this right...??? "SELECT * FROM RECOMMEND WHERE rID NOT IN '$arr'";

Comment: NO, it's NOT. use IMPLODE as i said more than 10 times - i already gave an example of this in my answer (and some others did the same exaple too), but it seems like you aren't reading what peaople write.

Comment: till now, and after all those tips and hints - in my answer and in a lot of comments, you havn't used var-dump() to print out what you're getting as result / you havn't echo'ed your $query from your script and copied that to execute it directly and you havn't tried to use IMPLODE to build your query as it should be - i've been realy patient with this till now, but now i'm going to vote this to close, as there will never be an answer if you don't work to get one.

Comment: @oezi: the array is already comma seperated... it appears like this: 1,3 when i write print_r($arr);

Comment: @all: thanks every one got it... Sorry for any pain caused as a result of my response...

Comment: @oezi: sorry for having tested ur patience.. was working with the belief that i already use implode()...

Comment: thats not the point - sounds like you don't even know what arrays are... why don't you try to do what i said? if you had simply tried it when i wrote, you could have saved us over one hour of time...

Comment: @oezi: b4 leaving could u please tell me wat u meant with: 1. use var_dump... 2) echoed ur $query... am new to php... please

Comment: var_dump() is a function that displays what type of variable the input is - you should have done var_dump($result) so you would have seen that it's not an object (and so you can't use fetch_object on it) / with echo, i mean you should have written `echo $q;`, copy that and execute it on your database instead of re-writing the query

Comment: also as i am new to stack overflow.. i did not earlier understand wat u meant by don;t comment and only edit.. so that might have prevented me 4m seeing ur replies...

Comment: @oezi: oh.. thanks mate ... u really taught me few new things 2day...

Comment: everyone is new sometimes and you can't know everything from the first day - i hope you've learned now ;) - and, what you should try to do from the first day on: accept an answer on every single question by checking the tick-mark on the left of the best answer.

Comment: yep.. I did.. Have i checked urs as the best answer..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should:

- format you code
- exactly describe what's you problem; if there's an error message, please post that message
- provide as much reasonable information as you can, so it's easy for us to see what you're trying to do

**EDIT:** some more points:

- show the error-message you're getting
- output the sql-statement that gets executed and try to execute it by hand (using phpmyadmin something similar)
- `var_dump` or `print_r` your result and see what you get - if it's `false`, think about what could be wrong: either your sql returns zero rows or there's a failure in it - just one of those two possibilitys
- if you get additional information, edit your question and list it there, don't force everybody to read every comment on every answer till now - you've given some information, but it's spread to everywhere
- `fetch_object` won't be the problem - the problem is, as said, either a result with zero rows or a bad statement

till now, this is just a comment, my attempt to answer your question (it's not realy clear whats your problem):

sounds like you havn't understood how NOT IN works and havn't looked at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/any-in-some-subqueries.html). you query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname where col1 NOT IN (1, 2, 3);
             # values of your array here ^^^^^^^
```

to build that from an php-array, you could use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) or something similar.

**EDIT:** a very basic sollution could look like this (not that you should check the input to avoid sql-injection and such stuff):

```
// for simple numerical values
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname where col1 NOT IN (".implode(", ",$myArray).")";

// for strings
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname where col1 NOT IN ('".implode("', '",$myArray)."')";
```

Comment: I think i don't have problem with the NOT IN statement... have problem only when i use fetch_object to print the result set..

Comment: i don't think there could be a problem with that - have you tried outputting your sql and executed it in phpmyadmin (or whatever) by hand? do you get error messages or the expected result?

Comment: i get : Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in

Comment: so, whats the problem? your result is no object, as it sais - please var_dump() your result and see what you get. don't let us grill out every piece of information from you - _you_ wan't to get help...

Comment: but the result is working when i use: where col1=value; the error occurs when i use: where col1 not in...

Comment: addition to my last commet: i'm sure you will get 'false' - and thats what you get if your sql doesn't return anything or you have a failure in it. execute it by hand with phpmyadmin, please - and take a look at the [documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.msql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: sorry the query seems to work when i directly query the database.. fetch_object works when i use : where col1=value... but not when i use not in...

Comment: to you last comment: simply do what myself and the others said, we want to help but you aren't giving us the information we need, you aren't doing what you should do and you're fighting against every hint we give - so, a last time: execute your query by hand, see what you get, read the error-message and come back with full information - it's not funny to help someone who doesn't obey on so many hints.

Comment: and: please take a look at the edits to my answer, it's not useful to discuss about this in the comments. edit your question, so everybody can see the new insights.

Comment: i said it more than once: var_dump() your result / post the error-message / execute the query by hand (the outputtet from your script, _Don't_ retype it by hand, maybe you're correcting the failure doing this and you don't recognize - execute _exactly_ the query from your script) / all the points listet in my answer above . and: _edit_ your post to show the result of _all_ this points, don't post it into a comment, please.

Comment: I have an array that currently holds 1,3..i.e $arr = {1,3}; i want to frame a query as the one i gave above.. as follows: $q = "select * from tbl where col1 not in ('$arr')"; That works fine... Next i execute it.. $res=$mysqli->query($q); That also works.. Next i need to display the resultset returned by $res. But i get an error when i use: $row = $res->fetch_object(); the error is with the last query... which works when i use: select * from tbl where col1 = '1'; The "NOT IN" query works drectly in the database...

Comment: DON'T post this into a comment where only i can see it, ADD this to your QUESTION. and, if' you're realy building your query with $q = "select * from tbl where col1 not in ('$arr')";, thats the problem we're talking about the wholte time: you CAN'T do this, use IMPLODE like it's posted in my answer - please ECHO your $q and execude THAT, don't type it by hand. i realy don't know if this is so hard to understand.

Comment: ok, again, as it looks like you havn't seen my last comment: READ my answer again, you CAN'T build your query like you do - you must use IMPLODE like i did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

use `select * from tblname where col1 NOT IN ('value1','value2',...,'valueX')`

Comment: where does your array come from? in that case you need to create a string dynamicaly from that array and put it in your query

Answer (score 1):

Post the code you have, this works (if I understood your question right):

`select userid,username
from users
where userid NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
limit 10`

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM ABC HAVING ID NOT IN $_SESSION[preferences]'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

Comment: have problem when i use this: $row=$res->fetch_object();

Comment: @Kailash: what does 'problem' mean? why don't you post the error-message?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a NULL in your "array".  That will cause NOT IN() to behave in a way you don't expect.  Check for that.

Comment: have no problem in NOT IN... have problem only while trying to print the resultset...

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your exact query to be sure, but NOT IN is not followed by an array.  its followed by (a, b, c) comma delimited string within parentheses

```
$inString = "(" . implode(", ", $array) . ")"; //looks like ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE col1 NOT IN $inString"
```

-=edit in response to comment--

```
$mysqli = mysqli( host, user, password, db);

$inString = "(" . implode(", ", $_SESSION['preferences']) . ")"; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE ID NOT IN $inString"; 

$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$obj = $mysqli->fetch_object();
```

Do you have all of these steps?  The issue is that 'false'->fetch_object() is no good.  'false' is whats returned when a query has an error or has no results.  This appears to be because your query is bad.

Comment: have tried that.. but in order to print the result returned, one has to use fetch_object()... right???

Comment: i think im gonna need your exact code to explain for you here, and what database are you using?  you need to execute the query with mysql_query($sql, $conn) ( or whatever else if you dont use mysql) before you use mysql_fetch_object or whatever to get the result

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM ABC HAVING ID NOT IN $_SESSION[preferences]'"; $result = $mysqli->query($query); –  

 
have problem when i use this: $row=$result->fetch_object();

Comment: i dont know mysqli well but i think the only problem is with the query string, ill try to correct

Comment: sorry the query seems to work when i directly query the database.. fetch_object works when i use : where col1=value... but not when i use not in...

Comment: he's being really patient and trying to explain to you.  fetch_object is NOT the problem.  the problem is you have a bad query, and $res never contains a result (instead it is false).  as such, you cannot call $res->fetch_object.  If you don't believe me or him, echo_r($res)

Comment: i don't get anything when i use echo_r($res);

Comment: thats what false does.  change your query!

Comment: I have an array that currently holds 1,3..i.e $arr = {1,3}; i want to frame a query as the one i gave above.. as follows: $q = "select * from tbl where col1 not in ('$arr')"; That works fine... Next i execute it.. $res=$mysqli->query($q); That also works.. Next i need to display the resultset returned by $res. But i get an error when i use: $row = $res->fetch_object(); the error is with the last query... which works when i use: select * from tbl where col1 = '1'; The "NOT IN" query works drectly in the database...

Comment: $q = "select * from tbl where col1 not in ('$arr')"; That works fine... Next i execute it.. $res=$mysqli->query($q);                ____THESES DO NOT WORK! YOU JUST DON'T NOTICE UNTIL fetch_object_____

Comment: if you don't believe me, echo $q right before the query. run it in manually.  it does not work

Comment: what u said is correct.. By working i meant that the query as it is works when i do it directly in the database...

Comment: no it doesn't.  it works when you remove the NOT IN clause, which you are using incorrectly.

Comment: @jon_darkstar: even this does not work: $query = "select * from tbl where col1 NOT IN '(1,2)'";

Comment: SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE ID NOT IN (1, 3)

Comment: that is the desired query.  that is exactly what $q should hold.  I have described how to get that and so have several other posters